# How to predict with label missing

Tags: machine-learning, missing-data

I have be given a set of data where most label data (dependent variable) is missing (NaN). Precisely on 100000 rows only 1412 contain a 1 or 0 (the others contain NaN). 
I was first thinking "let's drop the other rows" but i fear to get a relly poor model with so few data (but I will run this way if I have no better idea!). Then I told myself "perhaps with open data i can fill the holes" but the label to predict is : [if yes or no the building contain a cellar], information I feel I can't get on public (government) database ...

What could you suggest me ? It is the first time i get such a problem ...

Comment: You are pretty much screwed, only 1.4 % of  your data is complete. You could try using clustering to assign a class to the cases with missing labels.